# Limit query to only access objects within namespace?

Tags: mongodb, namespaces, mongoengine, mongodb-query, access-control

I want each [MongoDB [sub] database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-database) to have access to a specific database (`central`); as well as access to query anything within their own database/namespace.

How do I set this up? - I am using mongoengine BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection level authentication as outlined here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/

Specifically this section of the authentication manual:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-roles-collection/#a-user-defined-role-specifies-privileges

You can set permissions with documents:

```
{
  _id: "myApp.appUser",
  role: "appUser",
  db: "myApp",
  privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "data" },
         actions: [ "insert", "update", "remove", "compact" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "system.indexes" },
         actions: [ "find" ] }
  ]
}
```